Pyinstaller - "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'" for big FastAPI project
I have following folder structure for my FastAPI based backend project. I would like to do code obfuscation and ship in docker image.
├── alembic
│ ├── env.py
│ └── versions
│     ├── initial.py
├── alembic.ini
├── app
│ ├── helpers
│ │ ├── helper1.py
│ │ ├── helper2.py
│ ├── __init__.py
│ ├── routers
│ │ ├── routers1
│     ├── routera.py
│     └── __init__.py
│ │ ├── routers2
│ ├── __init__.py
│ └── startup
│     ├── start1.py
│     └── __init__.py
│ ├── main.py


When i run pyinstaller main.spec, it creates dist and build folders. Then after i copy that to container and start application (./dist/main/main) it is giving ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app' error.
Here is my main.spec file
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


a = Analysis(
    ['app/main.py'],
    pathex=['/home/user/project/'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=['tensorboard', 'asyncpg.pgproto.pgproto', 'app'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=['tkinter'],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='main',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=False,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=False,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='main',
)


I don't know what am i missing.
The app module should be resolvable for uvicorn.
